# Spinpossible group theory

Tags: group-theory, rotations

Do any two spins on Spinpossible commute? If so what is the algorithm or way in which they commute. More curious than anything.

Comment: You might want to read this article: https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.6645

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider the spin of the $2\times2$ top left square followed by the spin of the $2\times2$ bottom left square. Now, do this by the opposite order. See what happens to the middle square. In the first case, it is taken to the top left square, whereas in the second case it is taken to the bottom left square.